# Cascading data select Dropdown create using javascript using JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to Create Cascading data table using java script but it's not printing data properly.
I want to crete drop down when I select asset from dropdown , it load all section name from that asset and when I select sections fron thier child it select Ultrasonic sections name.
Also in asset it's populating 4 time "asset 4". It should print 1 time only.
I tried to debuge but it's not working . can any one help me?

And I want to do this in JavaScript only
JAVASCRIPT

```
var stateObject = '{"uri": "/assets/4afd3544-cea1-363d-ba29    e39831d8930d","name": "Asset 4","sections": [{"uri": "/assets/2dc11152-7b85-   35d7-8af6-c48ca4397d9f","sectionId": null, "name": "Section    1","ultrasonicSensors": null,"temperatureSensors":   null,"ultrasonicSensorPositions": [{"ultrasonicSensorPositionId":"1395","sensorPositionName":"MeasurementPosition 1","diameter": "0","rotation": "0","sequenceNumber": null,  "sectionId": "/assets/2dc11152-7b85-35d7-8af6-c48ca4397d9f"}]}]}';

  var json = JSON.parse(stateObject);

window.onload = function () {
var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
    countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
    citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");

for (state in json) {
 stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(json.name , "");

}

stateSel.onchange = function () {
    countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
      countySel.options[0].text = "Please select state first"
      citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
      return; // done   
    }  
    countySel.options[0].text = "Please select county"
    var x = JSON.stringify(json.sections);

   // alert(x)

    for (var county in x) {

    countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, x);
    }
    if (countySel.options.length==2) {
      countySel.selectedIndex=1;
      countySel.onchange();


    }  

}

stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded

countySel.onchange = function () {
    citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
      citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
      return; // done   
    }  
    citySel.options[0].text = "Please select city"

    var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
    }
    if (citySel.options.length==2) {
      citySel.selectedIndex=1;
      citySel.onchange();
    }
}
 }
```

Here is [js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfuusp9p/170/)

Comment: Your question title is data table but your fiddle is creating select elements, it is the wrong title or fiddle? @aaakanks

Comment: And by the way your JSON looks like there is only one section and the asset 4 is coming from the top object, tried in your fiddle

Comment: You're setting the values of the first selection to `""`. That's why you're getting the error. Later you're trying to access members of `stateObject`, which is still a String, as opposed to `json`, which is the parsed Object. You need to do _way_ more basic debugging before posting here. Did you even check your browser's console?

Comment: Sorry by mistake I gave tital about table .

Comment: I tried to debug but it's not giving any section name value in second dropdown.